# Better Rails 3 Asset Handling for  `cap deploy`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, assets, sprockets, precompile

I notice the default "deploy" task does the asset precompilation on the remote machine, which has these ill effects:

- Weird glitchy assets during the time it's precompiling (on the live site)
- Errors in the config cause downtime with a 500 response code
- The task to take a long time

I've seen this, which mitigates the problem a tiny bit by not causing you to precompile when you don't have anything to precompile: [Speed up assets:precompile with Rails 3.1/3.2 Capistrano deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016002/speed-up-assetsprecompile-with-rails-3-1-3-2-capistrano-deployment)

But there must be a better solution.

Has anyone tried these:

1. Always deploy to a "staging" location, where you can test everything out, then add some kind of `cap enliven` task that somehow tells the web server frontend to start using the other port? (I could manually manage this with editing the nginx `upstream` and restarting it, then I could automate that a bit with an include in the `nginx.conf` and a cap task to tie it together.)
2. Precompile locally then simply push the files over via rsync. I prefer #1, but this would be a smaller step that would probably work as a better default than the current behavior.

Am I missing something obvious? I'm am new to Rails assets + Capistrano deployment, but it seems like the best practices of deployment aren't available right out of the box on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- precompile assets before deploy
- compile it server-side in background
- leave it to `delayed_job` or another queue management system

Comment: Hi Alexander!

If you precompile, how do you integrate that into the Capistrano `deploy` so it doesn't precompile on the server?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if locally precompiled assets could be used on the server you can precompile it and then upload to server using Capistrano upload methods.