# Rails assets missing after Capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm building a VPS, and it's deployed via Capistrano, database connected etc, but there are no assets available to the page - it is basic html only.

The assets appear to be compiled, and exist in the **shared** directory.

From the page html:

```
<link href="/assets/application-a1b5d69aeaff709fd3dce163c559b38b.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application-0ebd07089629f8c6880dddfb688d525d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The asset files appear to exist in the **shared** directory:

```
assay@assaypipeline:~/apps/assay/shared/assets$ ls application-  a1b5d69aeaff709fd3dce163c559b38b.css
application-a1b5d69aeaff709fd3dce163c559b38b.css
```

When I **view, source** and then click on the hyperlink to the asset path, I get a 404 not found from Nginx.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Martin M (accepted answer) for help. The steps I took, from the ~/apps/(app name)/current directory on the server.

```
$ bundle install
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

Obviously it would be better to include this in the Capistrano recipe.

**EDIT - Capfile **

```
load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your precompiled assets should reside in `public/assets`, see [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)
normally you create them by running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

as part of your deployment.
The shared stuff is to provide old stuff over several deploys.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016369/1065703)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should the precompile be run on the development machine or the production server? Is there some way to include this in the Cap deploy?

Comment: the "standard" way is to activate the line `load 'deploy/assets'` in `Capfile`. It runs `precompile` on the server on every deploy.

Comment: I do have that. I've added my capfile above.

Comment: To be honnest, I'm using a hack to precompile the assets on my MacBook (much faster than my server) only when needed and `rsync` to the production server. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mameier/6028371), some code in my `config/deploy.rb`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might not be in asset compilation and deployment. 
Try changing nginx root /home/deploy/app_name/public; to /home/deploy/app_name/current/public; in nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

following is my configuration file

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/app_name/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great! That was the issue.