# No such file or directory(public/assets/manifest*)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano, manifest

During my rails(3.2.16v) deploy with capistrano v3 I am getting the following error.

**$cap development deploy --trace**

```
DEBUG [014a40e4] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/my_app/releases/20140117124107/public/assets ] on 50.13.220.55
DEBUG [014a40e4] Command: [ -L /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/my_app/releases/20140117124107/public/assets ]
DEBUG [014a40e4] Finished in 0.602 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [9c5901ab] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/my_app/releases/20140117124107/public/assets ] on 50.13.220.55
DEBUG [9c5901ab] Command: [ -d /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/my_app/releases/20140117124107/public/assets ]
DEBUG [9c5901ab] Finished in 0.639 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

**//// this error is at the end of the trace**

** Invoke deploy:assets:backup_manifest (first_time)

** Execute deploy:assets:backup_manifest

```
DEBUG [a08f4c02]    cp: 
DEBUG [a08f4c02]    cannot stat `/home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/my_app/releases/20140117064709/public/assets/manifest*'
DEBUG [a08f4c02]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [a08f4c02]    
cap aborted!
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:backup_manifest
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: Nothing written
>
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

I don't have any assets folder in my local machine too. Can any body help me??

Comment: Something similar have been asked here. Hope it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720253/rails-assets-missing-after-capistrano-deploy

Comment: @MarkoJurinčič - I think this is for capistrano v2. I am using v3

Comment: Found another link. It is also for version 2. But maybe it can help you: http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano

Comment: @MarkoJurinčič - This also didnt workout

Answer (score 20):

This happens with sprockets 3.0.x and capistrano-rails, and seems fixed with capistrano-rails 1.1.3.

If your Gemfile has `gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'` (as recommended in the installation guide), just type `bundle update capistrano-rails` to upgrade.

See https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#113-apr-18-2015 or https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/111

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
touch /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/my_app/releases/20140117064709/public/assets/manifest
```

I think a previous `cap <env> deploy` that was misconfigured has gummed up the works, and now your forever doomed. Simply `touch`ing a manifest file, will allow the task `deploy:assets:backup_manifest` to keep on doing its thing, since it expects the previous builds manifest file to be there to clean up. So, give it something to clean. Anyways, this solved my problem.

`tl;dr;` Make trash, keep littering, someone, somewhere will clean up after you, in this case one previous precompile's trash is `assets_manifest_backup`'s treasure.

I had also ssh'ed to server, ensured that `RAILS_ENV=production bundle` worked just fine, and had to resolve some ssh deploy keys for a private git repo. That could have been the gum, gumming up my works.

Comment: Having the same error, it sufficed to `$ mkdir public/assets && touch public/assets/manifest` => `$ cap <env> deploy` => hurray. thanks peter

Answer (score 5):

Add to Gemfile `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'`

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This solution works for me. See https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/111. This issue is caused by sprocket 3 using .sprocket-manifest[blablabla] instead of .manifest[blablabla]

Answer (score 0):

Are you precompiling your assets ? maybe it will help to precompile your assets before deployng.