# Rails 4: how to compile only changed assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

For Rails 3, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016002/speed-up-assetsprecompile-with-rails-3-1-3-2-capistrano-deployment) and [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) look great.

For Rails 4, there seems to be [some controversy](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3/issues/61) over whether this has been fixed or not.

I'm currently using Rails 4 in production, and it seems that because Capistrano `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes` touches *all* assets, `deploy:assets:precompile` likewise re-compiles all of them. That recompilation is the single longest step in my `cap deploy`.

Ideally, this should be replaced by some checksum based manifest system, so that only those assets that have actually changed (or are dependent on ones that have changed) are re-compiled.

What is the best way to do this? (Assuming we're still doing it on the server, not the dev machine.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great blog post from the guys at codeclimate about this. I've taken a look at it but not gone through the steps in production.

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/10/02/high-speed-rails-deploys-with-git/

Comment: That seems like a pretty radical change (well beyond the amount I was talking about). Definitely interesting though.

Answer (score 2):

This guy got it right for Capistrano 3. Works well for me.
https://coderwall.com/p/aridag

Comment: They turned it into a gem: https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets

Answer (score 1):

This issue was discussed in https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/478
and the solution which seems to be okay is simply to deactivate the touching. In above issue there was talk about a configuration variable to use for this but i could not find any code references to it. Instead we now simply overwrite the task.

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    task :update_asset_mtimes, :roles => lambda { assets_role }, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    end
  end
end
```

Note: This is only true for capistrano version 2. I have no idea if version 3 still uses the same tasks or not.