# uninitialized constant Uglifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline

after deployment I get following error in production.log:

ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Uglifier

I deploy with asset pipeline enabled and everything works on another server (same configuration, same environment)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I was using custom capistrano tasks to compile assets only if really needed (similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016002/speed-up-assetsprecompile-with-rails-3-1-3-2-capistrano-deployment))

That error shows that assets were not compiled (because it was skipped by the custom task). Solution is to compile assets manually for the first time (like `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`)